# jsonp with asmx error 500

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, jsonp

when i try this it works perfact

```
 function test() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({ url: "http://testweb.com/myAPI.asmx/GetPersonTest",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { userid: 1 },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json.UserID + ' ' + json.FirstName + ' ' + json.LastName);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Hit error fn!");
    }
    });
}
```

in the same asmx, i have another method called as below

```
    function Post_test(){

var newURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname;
var user = document.getElementById('Username').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
debugger;
$.ajax({ url: "http://testweb.com/myAPI.asmx/GetPerson",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: user, emailID: email}),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json.UserID + ' ' + json.FirstName + ' ' + json.LastName);
    },
    error: function(json) {
        alert("Hit error fn!");
    }
});


}
```

This method do a insert into database and return the same as GetPersonTest. But when i call this through javascript and jsonp it gives 500 server error

When i check in debugger , it gives the below error

```
jQuery17106155389654450119_1401518867750({"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027username\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"});
```

Can anyone please help me on below. thanks

the head of method is

```
         <WebMethod(True)> _
    <ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
        Public Function GetPerson(ByVal username As String, ByVal emailID As String) As String

End Function
```

And when i check the header in developer tool it is below

```
callback:jQuery17106155389654450119_1401518867750
{"username":"testuser","emailID":"test@test.com"}:
_:1401518889467
Response Headersview source
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the parameter **username** is being used in the mentioned contract method. Because, your error is showing like the missing of **username** parameter.

Ensure this and post your reply soon.

Comment: i have added the method details in the question.

Comment: i have just check withchrome rest client and it is saying System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: username.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest() dont know what i am missing as i have supplied the username

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following changes :

1. Remove 'JSON.stringify' from data parameter, so it should look like

   data : {"username": user, "emailID": email}
2. The response format is mentioned as "WebMessageFormat.Json", so change the dataType to "json", in place of "jsonp".
3. As the is being sent as querystring and not JSON, you can safely omit "contentType" (or can remove just 'application/json').

Hope this helps.

Comment: json will not work cross domain. I need it to work in cross domain environment. thats why i am using jsonp

Comment: If you have access to server side code and can modify the response headers, set proper 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. In this case, cross domain JSON request will also work. Please refer [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing for CORS requests.